# Unable to print NSString assigned with NSScanner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, nsscanner

I am trying to scan for a specific string in an html file, assign it to an NSString then do things with the NSString. If it matters, I am doing this in Cocos2d.

My code looks like this:

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: htmlCodeString];
NSString* string;

[scanner scanUpToString:@"HTML CODE" intoString:NULL];
[scanner scanString:@"HTML CODE" intoString:NULL];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"STRING I NEED" intoString: &string];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

When I run the code, NSLog prints the name of the layer I am executing the code in.

I am confused because I followed this example by Apple to a T:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000147-BCIEFGHC
(scroll to the bottom)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the contents of `htmlCodeString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what `scanUpToString:intoString` returns. If it returns `NO`, the string wasn't found and the "into" string isn't modified. As you don't initialize your string, it contains some random garbage. You should initialize it to `nil` and then look into why your string isn't found.